# Updating took more than 5 seconds when loading local json file

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui, compiler-errors

I was trying to load some data from a local json file and it keep showing that

> "PreviewUpdateTimedOutError: Updating took more than 5 seconds

which made me can resume the canvas. I don't know what the bug is in my structure.
The json.file is downloaded from api

**my load json function:**

```
func loadJsonData() -> [Movie] {
    let filename : String="data.json"
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)else{
        fatalError("no file found")}
    guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
        fatalError("can't load") }
    guard let list = try? JSONDecoder().decode(movieData.self, from: data) else {
        fatalError("no file found") }
    return list.result
}
```

**my struct file:**

```
struct movieData:Codable {
    var result:[Movie]
}
struct Movie:Codable,Identifiable{
    var adult:Bool
    var backdrop_path:String
    var genre_ids:[Int]
    var id:Int
    var original_language:String
    var original_title:String
    var overview:String
    var popularity:Double
    var poster_path:String?
    var release_data:String
    var title:String?
    var video:Bool
    var vote_average:Double?
    var vote_count:Int
}
```

**my data.json**

```
{
       "result": [
            {
                "adult": false,
                "backdrop_path": "/yizL4cEKsVvl17Wc1mGEIrQtM2F.jpg",
                "genre_ids": [
                    28,
                    878,
                    12
                ],
                "id": 588228,
                "original_language": "en",
                "original_title": "The Tomorrow War",
                "overview": "The world is stunned when a group of time travelers arrive from the year 2051 to deliver an urgent message: Thirty years in the future, mankind is losing a global war against a deadly alien species. The only hope for survival is for soldiers and civilians from the present to be transported to the future and join the fight. Among those recruited is high school teacher and family man Dan Forester. Determined to save the world for his young daughter, Dan teams up with a brilliant scientist and his estranged father in a desperate quest to rewrite the fate of the planet.",
                "popularity": 3368.737,
                "poster_path": "/34nDCQZwaEvsy4CFO5hkGRFDCVU.jpg",
                "release_date": "2021-09-03",
                "title": "The Tomorrow War",
                "video": false,
                "vote_average": 7.8,
                "vote_count": 271
            },
}
```

**my contentview**

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    let moviedata: movieData
    let movies:[Movie]
    init(){
        self.moviedata = movieData(result: loadJsonData())
        movies=self.moviedata.result
    }
  
    var body: some View {
        
       Text("hello!?")
        
    }

}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

Comment: To avoid those timing problems it's highly recommended to use a View Model, a class conforming to `ObservableObject` which *`publishes`* when the data is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

decoder is sending fatal error in guard statement because
your json file is missing **]** at the end of the array in result the view is crashing .

and also in book struct change releaseDat**a** to releaseDat**e**

```
var releaseData : String
```

to

```
var releaseDate : String
```

data.json :

```
{
"result":
[
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/yizL4cEKsVvl17Wc1mGEIrQtM2F.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            28,
            878,
            12
        ],
        "id": 588228,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "The Tomorrow War",
        "overview": "The world is stunned when a group of time travelers arrive from the year 2051 to deliver an urgent message: Thirty years in the future, mankind is losing a global war against a deadly alien species. The only hope for survival is for soldiers and civilians from the present to be transported to the future and join the fight. Among those recruited is high school teacher and family man Dan Forester. Determined to save the world for his young daughter, Dan teams up with a brilliant scientist and his estranged father in a desperate quest to rewrite the fate of the planet.",
        "popularity": 3368.737,
        "poster_path": "/34nDCQZwaEvsy4CFO5hkGRFDCVU.jpg",
        "release_date": "2021-09-03",
        "title": "The Tomorrow War",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 7.8,
        "vote_count": 271
    }
]}
```

Comment: sharp eyes bro here, "... in book struct", I think you meant "...in Movie struct"

Answer (score 1):

in your `struct Movie` change

```
var release_data:String
```

to

```
var release_date:String
```

Comment: You mistakingly wrote the same line.

Comment: @Amr date, not data :)

Comment: sharp eyes bro 